# How to prevent image overlay from being unclickable

Tags: html, css

I have the following banner design to in corporate:

[image] (Click on image to see the full picture.)

Now the following bug exists , let me show it to you visually first:

[image] (Click to see full image).

Now the caption needs to come much below , but because i have used a image and absolutely positioned it , the red area is actually still the image. I need it to be the banner , as the dots need to be clickable.

How do i go about doing this , one solution i tried was using a div instead of an image , giving it a height and then adding the image as a background, but this amounts to doing the same thing and also creates the same bug , I know this is a difficult problem to solve , but can i use an image and still get away I.E. NOt have this bug , thats what i am looking for right now , i know there might be a canvas or SVG solution, But i can't use canvas or SVG for this project.

The bug can be seen **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/banner-bug/new-index.html)**.

Thank you.

Comment: You can play around with z-index values of the image and the overlay. Also the circles are clickable in chrome. Isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: I believe nobody understands you. Please edit your question and try to just tell us what is desired. let the rest for the reader

Comment: @AmitJS94 yes but remember the text has to come much below then it is in the demo ! :) .. so it won't work when i do that

Comment: Its that your base image overlaps by 'position:absolute' as to why its not clickable so you could align the image better but @Bluesight suggestion will apply a fix to that missalignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply "pointer-events: none" to your image, then it will work:

```
.curved-img-wrpr img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The Image will now not block your element below.

MDN Explanation:

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse
>   events, the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the
>   element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

I believe MDN's explanation pretty much sums it up.

Comment: I have tried and yes it's working, dots are clickable with above solution.

Comment: Please check his answer, give him a tick if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might be support issues with `pointer-events: none;` but i'm not really sure about it. I played with `z-index` and in your link reference, i found that if i give `z-index:99999` to `<div class="sp-layer">`, those DOTS become clickable..!!
Hope this helps.